# Why is my WordPress function ignoring If condition?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php if($salePrice !== $price) : ?>
  <span class="ecomm-regular-price">
    <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() .  $price ?>
  </span>
<?php endif; ?>
<span class="ecomm-sale-price">
  <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $salePrice; ?>
</span>
```

When `$salesPrice` is equal to `$price` , the contents of the `.ecomm-regular-price` span should not show. However, while `$price` acts as I expected and does not show, for some reason the currency symbol from `get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()` does show.

Can someone please explain to me why `get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()` is ignoring the condition and how to stop it from showing unless the condition is met ?

Comment: You have `<span class="ecomm-sale-price">` that **always** showing `get_woocommerce_currency_symbol()` and sale price outside any `if` conditions. That's why it always showing

Answer (score 0):

Put the sale price in an "else" block:

```
<?php if($salePrice !== $price) : ?>
  <span class="ecomm-regular-price">
    <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() .  $price ?>
  </span>
<?php else: ?>
  <span class="ecomm-sale-price">
    <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $salePrice; ?>
  </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```